# How to import entire latitude and longitude column in python if I want to find the time zone using it

Tags: python-3.x, timezone, location, latitude-longitude

I have various values of latitude and longitude with which I want to know the location so that I can find the time zone at that location in python.

I have the code where I can do it for one latitude and longitude value. similarly, I want to do it for numerous other values by importing the entire column in that code.

Comment: Please have another look at [ask] and provide a [mre] that illustrates the specific problem you're facing. In general, for mapping lat/lon to a timezone, have a look at [timezonefinder](https://github.com/jannikmi/timezonefinder).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.